# Change name of NuGet package in Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: nuget, azure-devops

I need a way to set or change the name of a NuGet package which is created in Visual Studio Team Services. I've tried changing the name of the Assembly Title of the project which is being turned into a NuGet package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to change the AsssemblyName in the .csproj file of your project.